# Identify and Paste the named range that was most recently updated

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA to identify the name of the named range that was most recently updated. I have been trying to use Worksheet Changes but have not gotten anywhere. In other words, if I have three named ranges "A", "B", and "C" all on the same worksheet and the named range "B" is changed. I want the name "B" not the data in the range to be pasted in a cell on a different worksheet. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Are all the named ranges on the same sheet?  Are the updates to those ranges being done directly to the ranges manually, or are they the product of formulas in the named ranges?

Comment: Share with us your 'Worksheet Changes' sub and we'll help you get it working..

Comment: Is there any overlap among the Named ranges ??

Comment: All of the updates are manual and all of the named ranges are distinct. The named ranges do not share any cells.

Comment: Are they on the same sheet?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same sheet.

Comment: Please note that **C is not a valid name for a Named Range.**

Comment: Then please show the code that is not working, so we can help solve the problem.

Comment: you could test if a specific name was changed by `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Name1")) Is Nothing Then 'Name1 changed` would that fit your needs? If not: Are your names in the workbook scope or in the worksheet scope if you look into the name manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes that the "other" worksheet is named "track" and that the three Named Ranges are named "A", "B", and "D" *(for some reason "C" is not valid)*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    msg = ""

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A")) Is Nothing Then msg = "A"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B")) Is Nothing Then msg = "B"
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D")) Is Nothing Then msg = "D"
    If msg = "" Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Sheets("track").Range("A1").Value = msg
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can test if any name intersects with the changed target

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim N As Name
    For Each N In Application.Names 'loop throug all names in the workbook scope
        If Not Intersect(Target, N.RefersToRange) Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print N.Name 'print changed name
            Exit For 'stop loop if a name intersects
        End If
    Next N
End Sub
```

Depending on if you need to check the workbook scope names or the worksheet scope names you need to use either `Application.Names` or `Me.Names` in the `Each` loop.

If you have overlapping names remove the `Exit For` to output all changed names.

Answer (score 0):

In your worksheet code: here is an example.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("RangeA")) Is Nothing Then
    ThisWorkbook.worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("a cell").Value = "A"
elseif Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("RangeB")) Is Nothing Then
    ThisWorkbook.worksheets("SomeSheet").Range("a cell").Value = "B"
'etc ....
End If

End Sub
```